# Camera doesn't point to the place i want using SceneKit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

i'm learning `scenekit` these days.but there's some problem.

i create an .scn file and put a sphere at (0,0,0)
and i use these codes to put a camera on a node

```
let frontCamera = SCNCamera()
frontCamera.yFov = 45
frontCamera.xFov = 45
let topNode = SCNNode()
topNode.camera = frontCamera
topNode.position = SCNVector3(4, 0, 0)
topNode.orientation = SCNQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 0)
scene!.rootNode.addChildNode(topNode)
topView.pointOfView = topNode
topView.allowsCameraControl = true
```

when i run i cannot see anything until I click on my simulator and use this property , `allowsCameraControl` I set.

could you tell me where is wrong about my code?Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating an `SCNQuaternion` of all zeroes doesn't really mean anything. You've specified a rotation of 0, along an axis specified by an all-zero "unit" vector. If you try this modified version of your code, you'll see nothing has really changed after you try to change `topNode`'s orientation. You're still rotating around an axis that is zero in all 3 components:

```
let topNode = SCNNode()
topNode.camera = frontCamera
topNode.position = SCNVector3(4, 0, 0)
print(topNode.orientation, topNode.rotation)
-> SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0) SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 0.0)

topNode.orientation = SCNQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 0)
print(topNode.orientation, topNode.rotation)
->SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 1.0) SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0, w: 3.14159)
```

You've moved out the X axis 4 units to place your camera (`topNode.position`). In the usual orientation, that means 4 units to the right, with positive Y running from bottom of your screen to the top, and positive Z running out of the screen to your eye. You want to rotate around the Y axis. The camera's orientation is down its parent node's minus-Z axis. So let's rotate 1/4 way clockwise, and try setting the `rotation` instead (easier for me to think about than quaternions):

```
topNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, Float(M_PI_2))
print(topNode.orientation, topNode.rotation)
-> SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, w: -4.37114e-08) SCNVector4(x: 0.0, y: 1.0, z: 0.0, w: 3.14159)
```

You will probably find it helpful to log out, or even display, the camera node's `rotation`, `orientation`, and `eulerAngles` (they all express the same notion, just using different axes) as you manipulate the camera manually.

For completeness, here's the entire `viewDidLoad`:

```
@IBOutlet weak var sceneView: SCNView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    sceneView.scene = SCNScene()

    let sphere = SCNSphere(radius: 1.0)
    let sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: sphere)
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(sphereNode)

    let frontCamera = SCNCamera()
    frontCamera.yFov = 45
    frontCamera.xFov = 45
    let topNode = SCNNode()
    topNode.camera = frontCamera
    topNode.position = SCNVector3(4, 0, 0)
    sceneView.scene?.rootNode.addChildNode(topNode)
    print(topNode.orientation, topNode.rotation)
    topNode.orientation = SCNQuaternion(0, 0, 0, 0)
    print(topNode.orientation, topNode.rotation)

    topNode.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, Float(M_PI_2))
    print(topNode.orientation, topNode.rotation)
}
```